# Yii2 QueryBuilder : How to check if a string contains any string of a column in MySQL and vice versa?

Tags: yii2

I want to build this :

```
SELECT makek FROM golo WHERE golo.name LIKE "%string%" OR string LIKE CONCAT("%", golo.name, "%")
```

using queryBuilder.

`golo.name LIKE "%string%"` is not a problem but `string LIKE CONCAT("%", golo.name, "%")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the string format for where condition like this

```
$query->select('makek')->
   from('golo')->
   where('golo.name LIKE "%string%" OR string LIKE CONCAT("%", golo.name, "%")');


$query->select('makek')->
   from('golo')->
   where('golo.name LIKE "%string%"')->
   orWhere('string LIKE CONCAT("%", golo.name, "%")');
```